# How to call Asp.net web Api login and token authentication

Tags: typescript

**How to call Asp.net web Api login and token authentication** in ionic 2 and angular 2 front-end validation

error

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing."}
```

Login.ts

```
login(loginForm: NgForm) {
    if (loginForm && loginForm.valid) {
        let username = loginForm.form.value.username;
        let password = loginForm.form.value.password;
        var result = this.authService.token(username, password).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.result = response;
            },
            error => {
                var results = error['_body'];
           });
    } else {
        this.errorMessage = 'Please enter a user name and password.';
    };
}
```

services.ts

```
token(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    if (!username || !password) {
        return;
    }
    let body = JSON.stringify({ grant_type: 'password', username: username, password: password });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.logindetail, body, options) // ...using post request
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: tutorials or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.